# python-click reading arguments incorrectly (splitting one word into letters)

Tags: python, python-click

I have a click app with groups which is supposed to take 2 required arguments and 2 optional arguments and send them down the line, but for some reason in the command line, click splits the first argument into individual letters. So instead of seeing `api-keychain store test`, click sees `api-keychain store t e s t`

## Command line output:

```
>>> api-keychain store test test

<<< Usage: e [OPTIONS] APPLICATION KEY [EXPIRATION] [USERDATA]
<<< Try 'e --help' for help.
<<< 
<<< Error: Missing argument 'KEY'.
```

## Source code:

```py
@click.group()
def cli():
    pass

@cli.command(no_args_is_help=True)
@click.argument('application')
@click.argument('key')
@click.argument('expiration', required=False, default='1/1/9999')
@click.argument('userdata', required=False, default='{}')
def store(application, key, expiration, userdata):
    '''Stores APPLICATION, KEY, and optionally EXPIRATION, and USERDATA in a new key. Creates a keychain if one does not already exist.'''
    store(application,key,expiration,userdata)
```

Comment: I think your problem lies with calling `store(application,key,expiration,userdata)` from inside the `def store(application,key,expiration,userdata):` function.   I tried locally and saw the same output you posted above but if I commented out the call to `store(application,key,expiration,userdata)` and replaced it with: `print(f"{application} {key} {expiration} {userdata}")` things functions as I would expect.

Comment: I just realized that I am using the same function name for the click function and the actual store function. How did I miss that?

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution. I had named the active function "store" but also named my CLI command "store", so it was breaking the argument parser. When I renamed my application function to "api_store", and refactored the code:

```py
def store(application, key, expiration, userdata):
    '''Stores APPLICATION, KEY, and optionally EXPIRATION, and USERDATA in a new key. Creates a keychain if one does not already exist.'''
    api_store(application,key,expiration,userdata)
```

it resolved the issue and began parsing correctly.